# How to use Devise Invitable with Rails 7 and Turbo Stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7, devise-invitable

I have a Rails 7 app with Devise 4.9 and Devise Invitable 2.0.7.

In `initializers/devise.rb` I have set this navigational_formats to:

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

This allows the devise forms to work correctly.

However, this config breaks the devise invitation forms for example:
This form `app/views/devise/invitations/new.html.erb`
has

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

If I try to submit this form I get this error:

```
undefined method `users_url' for #<Users::InvitationsController:0x00000000050dc0>
```

If I add this to my routes

```
resources :users
```

Then I get this error when I submit the form:

```
undefined method `empty?' for #<User id: nil,  ...
```

If I add `data: {turbo: false}` to the invitation's form_for, then the form will submit BUT it will not work with turbo stream.

How do I make Devise Invitable work with this Devise configuration?

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

Or how should i handle this situation?

Comment: routes.rb make sure `devise_for :users`

Comment: I have   devise_for :users, controllers: {
    invitations: 'users/invitations'
  } in the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Application error" in the rails error view had this:

ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template users/invitations/new, devise/invitations/new, devise/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:turbo_stream], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}

This error is saying "I couldn't find your 'new' template."

I was able to make the invitation form work like this:

In app/views/devise/invitations/new.html.erb:

```
<%= render "form", resource: resource %>
```

In app/views/devise/invitations/new.turbo_stream.erb:

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace dom_id(resource) do %>
  <%= render "form", resource: resource %>
<% end %>
```

In app/views/devise/invitations/_form.html.erb I made the form_for  like normal but added an id that was equal to dom_id(resource):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_invitation_path, html: { method: :post, id: dom_id(resource) }) do |f| %>
```

This will prevent the error because Rails finds the `new.turbo_stream.erb` file and replaced the partial (if the form submission has errors).

For more info, see: https://rubydoc.info/github/hotwired/turbo-rails/Turbo/StreamsHelper